# Hook Menu and module prevalence

Tags: 7, routes

I am implementing the following in a module:

```
function foo_module_menu() {

    $items['taxonomy/term/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'subproducts_populate_taxo',
   'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK);

    return $items;
};
```

This hook doesn't seem to work, i assumed it was because of the taxonomy module having prevalence on this menu item, so i gave my module a -1 weight.

Now strange thing, it work but only after clear cache once after applying the weight change. If i reflush cache the Taxonomy module take prevalence again even though i didn't rechange the weight..

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to override existing menu entries.

Comment: Actually your solution seems better, according to my menu hook, will that code work ? 
`hook_menu_alter(&$items) {
 
  $items['taxonomy/term/%']['page callback'] =  'subproducts_populate_taxo';
[....]
}`

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks your suggestion, it ll probably come in handy later, though in the mean time i got it working by making the weight of my module lighter than the taxonomy. **Seems that to override menu items lighter module get prevalence.**